# Flutter pdf signature app is not working correctly

Tags: android, ios, flutter, mobile, syncfusion

Well i am trying to create a flutter pdf signature app the issue i am facing is that when i export the signature drawn and place it on a certain point where the signature is required on the singature position but when i save it. The signature is not place on a right place.

Result Before saving the pdf looks like this.
[image]

Result After saving the pdf looks like this.
[image]

Below is the code for saving the pdf with signature. For saving the document i am using syncfusion flutter pdf package

```
Future<String> saveEditedPdf(
      Uint8List signatureImage,
      File selectedPdf,
      int signaturePageNumber,
      double width,
      double height,
      Offset position) async {
    debugPrint("here1");
    //Create a new PDF document.
    final PdfDocument document =
        PdfDocument(inputBytes: selectedPdf.readAsBytesSync());
    debugPrint("here2");

//Get the existing PDF page.
    final PdfPage page = document.pages[signaturePageNumber];
    debugPrint("here3");

//Load the image using PdfBitmap.
    final PdfBitmap image = PdfBitmap(signatureImage);
    debugPrint("here4");

    double difference = height - 200;
//Draw the image to the PDF page.
    page.graphics.drawImage(
        image,
        Rect.fromLTWH(
            position.dx + width, position.dy + height, width, height));

    //Rect.fromLTWH(position.dx, position.dy, width, height)
    // Rect. fromPoints(
    //     position, Offset(position.dx + height, position.dy + height),),
    debugPrint("here5");

    //getting path
    Directory? appDirectory = await getExternalStorageDirectory();

    debugPrint(appDirectory.toString());

    // if(Platform.isIOS){
    //   appDirectory = getappli
    // }

    debugPrint("here6");

    String filePath =
        '${appDirectory?.path}/${(path.basename(selectedPdf.path))}';
    debugPrint("here7");

// Save the document.
    File(filePath).writeAsBytes(await document.save());
    debugPrint("here8");

    debugPrint("saved");

// Dispose the document.
    document.dispose();

    return filePath;
  }
```